# Build *.aar file with NDK Headers

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

i am using the android ndk with the new gradle-experimental plugin. Now i have my project structure like this:

- module with java and c++ code
- app with java and c++ code

Both are in one android studio project. Now my app c++ classes have dependencies to the module headers. I want to modify my build.gradle so that the headers i want to export are automatically exported (all headers in a file structure usually).

Can you give me a hint what the best way is to realize this? I will use this a lot so a beautiful solution with a bit more work is prefered.

I am thinking of a way to put headers inside the aar file, so that they are under the "exploded-aar" folder, where i can reimport them from my app.

Comment: Did you find a solution?